# How To Select Multiple TextBoxes In Presentation Mode, Copy & Paste Them To Another Slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to create an Action Plan section within my PowerPoint presentation based on customer selections from various slides in presentation mode.  I would like to present the topic slide and have the ability to select 1 or more items from it and once through each topic slide, copy and paste their selections beginning with the topic, followed by their selection.  I have attached images of the PowerPoint.  Slides 2 - 4 are topic slide examples, each containing a few comments to select from.  Slide 5 is the Action Plan slide that captures their selections and is an example of what I am hoping for.  I made an attempt at the coding, but failed horribly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. You can write your own and we'll help you get it working. But you might have to hire a VBA pro for this, it doesn't sound like a beginner project.

Comment: Understood...below is the code that I am running in slide 2.  When I run it from the module, it copies all of the options to slide 5.  When I am in presentation mode and click on a selection, the presentation moves to the next slide.  My question is how do I copy multiple selections to the clipboard while being able to copy an item when in presentation mode?

Comment: #Option Explicit
# Sub copyobjectsSLD2()
Dim myshape1 As Object
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myRange As Object

myArray = Array("TextBox 1", "TextBox 2", "TextBox 3", "TextBox 4")
  With ActivePresentation
    Set myshape1 = .Slides(2).Shapes.Range(myArray)
    myshape1.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Action = myshape1.Copy
    .Slides(5).Shapes.Paste
  End With
End Sub

Comment: You can't select anything in slideshow view, so selecting things is a non starter. You could add an action setting of RUN MACRO to each of the shapes you want to work with and have the macro start out Sub Whatever(oSh as Shape)  The macro could add oSh to a collection of shapes that you later add to a slide.

Answer (score 0):

Removing my question. Will revise it and submit along with my coding attempt.